# AWS glue run mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been learning about glue lately, and one question striked me out of nowhere. In which mode the glue job run, meaning we run spark jobs in standalone, cluster or local mode. What is the mode when it comes to glue jobs, considering it is also a pyspark job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From various docs and my experience on EMR vs. Glue:

- AWS Glue runs your ETL jobs in an Apache Spark Serverless environment. AWS Glue runs these jobs on virtual resources that it provisions and manages in its own service account. DPU's are the go. It's their own engineering, just like AWS EMR and with AWS Glue they have simplified things.
- AWS Glue versions 2.0 and later do not run on Apache YARN, so YARN settings do not apply.
- AWS have provided their own approach, the notions of StandAlone, YARN do not apply.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/how-it-works.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-runs.html